# <a> tag starts a new line with overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css

I wanted to know if there is a way to prevent a `<a>` tag from taking 2 line. I have put it in a `<span>` and I have set the overflow to hidden and text-overflow to ellipsis and the final result is the link being cut with '...' at the end, but the rest of the link starts a new line under it. is there a way to just end the link with '...' and ignore the rest?

Comment: Paste your code into your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The question had an accepted answer 10 minutes after I asked it, 1 hour later 5 folks pass by and mark it as off topic. Why? it was already a done deal, the question was answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
a{white-space:nowrap}
```

Comment: right what I was looking for! perfect